# How to read a text file and store with hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a text file with integers in 3 columns and with multiple entries for each number on the first column, like the sample above:

```
1 23 1
1 24 2
1 57 1
1 10 1
1 59 2
1 31 2
1 38 1
1 11 1
2 39 2
2 40 1
2 15 1
2 74 2
```

I can read the contents of the file with the code shown above

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt")))
        {
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } }
```

but I want to use hashmap to join all the entries for every different number of the first column in one line like this:

```
1 23 1 24 2 57 1 10 1 59 2 31 2 38 1
2 39 2 40 1 15 1 74 2
```

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use a hashmap for this task? It doesn't seem like the right data structure, particularly if you need the two output lines to be ordered as they appear in the file.

Comment: You can use a hashmap to store {number -> string}, then get the string corresponding to the current line's number (or create a new entry if there is none) and append the line (without the first number). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @TedHopp a friend told me to try this, but I'm confused. Could you provide some sample code for suggestion?

Comment: It sounds like a HashMap can't do what you are wanting because HashMap keys must be unique. You can't have a HashMap entry that looks like `1, 23` and another that looks like `1, 24`. Otherwise I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Also I believe what @TedHopp is referring to is that HashMap does not guarantee any consistent ordering of its entries.

Comment: @Radiodef I was thinking that in the hashmap I could have something like key:1 values:23 1 24 2 57 1 10 1 59 2 31 2 38 1, key:2 values:39 2 40 1 15 1 74 2

Comment: @Omen That's basically what I suggested, too. So again, what exactly is the problem, where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually I haven't used hashmap before and can't understand how this works.

Comment: So you want the numbers in the first column to correspond to a list of the values in column 2 and 3? For this I would just recommend a List and not a Map unless your column 1 can skip a value. Maps are more intended for situations where the keys do not have an integral ordering. If there is an integral order (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4...) this is more suited to some kind of array. Otherwise definitely use TreeMap and not HashMap. TreeMap is sorted.

Comment: @Radiodef Good point, assuming that the numbers are consecutive and actually ordered. However, if needed, order could also be restored afterwards.

Comment: Maybe you want a Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>.  They key to the map is the '1' or '2', and the values are an ArrayList of the numbers (23 1 24...).

Comment: It was a bad choice of sample, the rest of the text file is not sorted on any column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some basic code to get you started. This uses a TreeMap which will sort the entries. Read the blurb on [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to see why, which specifies that HashMap guarantees no ordering of the entries. It would be possible to use HashMap for this but I don't recommend it because you might have to make extra steps somewhere.

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>> rowMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>>();

// when you have your new line

String[] cols = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

if (cols.length < 1) {
    // handle error if there is not a key column
}

try {
    int colKey = Integer.parseInt(cols[0]);

    Integer[] colValues = new Integer[cols.length - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < cols.length; i++) {
        colValues[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(cols[i]);
    }

    if (!rowMap.containsKey(colKey)) {

        // add a new entry for this column number
        rowMap.put(colKey, new ArrayList<Integer[]>());
    }

    rowMap.get(colKey).add(colValues);

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle error if any columns don't have integers
}
```

Now what you have is a TreeMap containing a listing of all *rows* grouped by the number in column 1.

For your example document to print the entire map you can do the following:

```
// iterate by column 1 number in numerical order
for (Integer key : rowMap.keySet()) {

    // iterate by rows in this column in the order they were added
    for (Integer[] row : rowMap.get(key)) {
        String printout = key + ":";

        // iterate by columns in this row
        for (Integer col : row) {
            printout += " " + col;
        }

        System.out.println(printout);
    }
}
```

This will output the following:

```
1: 23 1
1: 24 2
1: 57 1
1: 10 1
1: 59 2
1: 31 2
1: 38 1
1: 11 1
2: 39 2
2: 40 1
2: 15 1
2: 74 2
```

So you can see this sorts your document based on the value in column 1. You could also print them in the format you showed in the OP, you'd just change the loop a little bit so the rows are added to the same line.

Some notes about using TreeMap this way:

- The numbers in column 1 can be *any integer*.
- The numbers in column 1 can be in *any order*.
- The rows can have *any number of columns* beyond the first one.

But when you list them using the Map they will always be grouped by the column 1 number and they will always be ordered numerically.

It could be somewhat simplified if you don't care about keeping the rows sorted as well in which case you can make a `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` or `TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` or even a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` if all you do is concatenate each row.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Seems I can't get of an error in the printing loop, saying that variable row is already defined in method, but I can't see where...

Comment: In the printing loop in my example I've declared `row` only once (`String row;`). Make sure that the second loop where the variable row gets assigned (looks like `row =`) isn't also a declaration (`String row =`). You can also declare and instantiate row at the same time if you want. It doesn't _really_ matter. I changed my example to show it that way.

Comment: @Radiodef You are really declaring `row` twice: once as `Integer[]` and once as `String`. I guess the first `row` should be `rows`.

Comment: I think It's done! I will post a reply with the code that worked for me for the record. Thank you all for helping!

Comment: @tobias_k Yeah you're right! I'll fix it. I had altered the structure halfway through writing and I guess I forgot to update some parts. : /

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap is an Object that maps a Key to a specific value. This is an implementation of what tobias_k is suggesting:

```
HashMap<int, String> map = new HashMap<int,String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt")))
        {
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // ** NEW CODE **
                // get first int in current line
                int first = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(0, sCurrentLine.indexOf(" ")))
                // get rest of line
                String rest = sCurrentLine.substring(sCurrentLine.indexOf(" ")).trim();
                // get what is currently in for key value and append to it what you just got
                map.put(first, map.get(first) + rest);

                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } }
```

And to print, you could do:

```
for(int key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(map.get(key));
}
```

**DISCLAIMER** may not be 100% valid syntax

Comment: Thanks for your reply, seems to work ok, just need some adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that worked for me better and shows all numbers aggregated for each different number in the first column. Thank you all for posting a solution. If you suggest any kind of change on this, please feel free to do so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sCurrentLine;
    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>> rowMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt")))
        {
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] cols = sCurrentLine.split(" ");

                if (cols.length < 1) {
                }

                try {
                    int colKey = Integer.parseInt(cols[0]);

                    Integer[] colValues = new Integer[cols.length - 1];

                    for (int i = 1; i < cols.length; i++) {
                        colValues[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(cols[i]);
                    }

                    if (!rowMap.containsKey(colKey)) {
                        rowMap.put(colKey, new ArrayList<Integer[]>());
                    }
                    rowMap.get(colKey).add(colValues);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
                for (Integer key : rowMap.keySet()) {
                    String row = key + ""; 
                    for (Integer[] rows : rowMap.get(key)) {
                        for (Integer col : rows) {
                            row += " " + col;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(row);
                }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```